# mobile java app

Tags: java, mobile, jar

I'm trying to change a mobile app which has been written in Java, I've extracted the .jar file which has resulted in the following directory tree:

```
.
|-- aa.class
|-- ab.class
|-- ac.class
|-- a.class
|-- ad.class
|-- ae.class
|-- af.class
|-- ag.class
|-- ah.class
|-- ai.class
|-- aj.class
|-- ak.class
|-- al.class
|-- am.class
|-- an.class
|-- ao.class
|-- ap.class
|-- aq.class
|-- ar
|-- ar.class
|-- as.class
|-- at.class
|-- au.class
|-- av.class
|-- aw.class
|-- ax.class
|-- ay.class
|-- az.class
|-- ba.class
|-- bb.class
|-- bc.class
|-- b.class
|-- bd.class
|-- be.class
|-- bf.class
|-- bg.class
|-- bh.class
|-- bi.class
|-- bj.class
|-- bk.class
|-- bl.class
|-- bm.class
|-- bn.class
|-- bo.class
|-- bp.class
|-- bq.class
|-- br.class
|-- bs.class
|-- bt.class
|-- bu.class
|-- bv.class
|-- bw.class
|-- bx.class
|-- by.class
|-- bz.class
|-- ca.class
|-- cb.class
|-- cc.class
|-- c.class
|-- cd.class
|-- ce.class
|-- cf.class
|-- cg.class
|-- ch.class
|-- ci.class
|-- cj.class
|-- ck.class
|-- cl.class
|-- cm.class
|-- cn.class
|-- co.class
|-- config.xml
|-- cp.class
|-- cq.class
|-- cr.class
|-- cs.class
|-- ct.class
|-- cu.class
|-- cv.class
|-- cw.class
|-- cx.class
|-- cy.class
|-- cz.class
|-- da.class
|-- db.class
|-- dc.class
|-- d.class
|-- dd.class
|-- de.class
|-- df.class
|-- dg.class
|-- dh.class
|-- di.class
|-- dj.class
|-- dk.class
|-- dl.class
|-- dm.class
|-- dn.class
|-- do.class
|-- dp.class
|-- dq.class
|-- dr.class
|-- ds.class
|-- dt.class
|-- du.class
|-- dv.class
|-- dw.class
|-- dx.class
|-- dy.class
|-- dz.class
|-- ea.class
|-- eb.class
|-- ec.class
|-- e.class
|-- ed.class
|-- ee.class
|-- ef.class
|-- eg.class
|-- eh.class
|-- ei.class
|-- ej.class
|-- ek.class
|-- el.class
|-- em.class
|-- en
|-- extra.png
|-- fa
|-- f.class
|-- g.class
|-- h.class
|-- i.class
|-- icon.png
|-- image
|   |-- arm.png
|   |-- help-back-nonetouch-en.png
|   |-- help-back-nonetouch-fa.png
|   |-- help-back-touch-en.png
|   |-- help-back-touch-fa.png
|   |-- help-navigate-nonetouch-en.png
|   |-- help-navigate-nonetouch-fa.png
|   |-- help-navigate-touch-en.png
|   |-- help-navigate-touch-fa.png
|   |-- help-search-nonetouch-en.png
|   |-- help-search-nonetouch-fa.png
|   |-- help-search-touch-en.png
|   |-- help-search-touch-fa.png
|   |-- help-transfer-nonetouch-en.png
|   |-- help-transfer-nonetouch-fa.png
|   |-- help-transfer-touch-en.png
|   |-- help-transfer-touch-fa.png
|   `-- minix.png
|-- index
|   |-- 0
|   |-- CHARS
|   |-- i
|   `-- INDEX
|-- j.class
|-- k.class
|-- keyboard
|   |-- alphanumeric-ar
|   |-- alphanumeric-default
|   |-- alphanumeric-fa
|   |-- qwerty-ar
|   |-- qwerty-default
|   `-- qwerty-fa
|-- layouts
|   |-- default-12
|   |-- default-ar
|   |-- default-en
|   |-- default-fa
|   |-- default-ru
|   |-- k800i-ar
|   |-- k800i-en
|   |-- k800i-fa
|   |-- list
|   |-- nokia6220-en
|   |-- nokia6220-fa
|   |-- nokia-en
|   |-- nokia-fa
|   |-- p990i-ar
|   |-- p990i-en
|   |-- p990i-fa
|   |-- sonyericsson-ar
|   |-- sonyericsson-en
|   `-- sonyericsson-fa
|-- l.class
|-- loading.png
|-- m.class
|-- META-INF
|   |-- MANIFEST.MF
|   `-- services
|       `-- org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory
|-- n.class
|-- o.class
|-- org
|   `-- minix
|       |-- aa.class
|       |-- ab.class
|       |-- ac.class
|       |-- a.class
|       |-- ad.class
|       |-- ae.class
|       |-- af.class
|       |-- ag.class
|       |-- ah.class
|       |-- b.class
|       |-- c.class
|       |-- d.class
|       |-- e.class
|       |-- f.class
|       |-- g.class
|       |-- h.class
|       |-- i.class
|       |-- j.class
|       |-- k.class
|       |-- l.class
|       |-- m.class
|       |-- Midlet.class
|       |-- n.class
|       |-- o.class
|       |-- p.class
|       |-- q.class
|       |-- r.class
|       |-- s.class
|       |-- t.class
|       |-- u.class
|       |-- v.class
|       |-- w.class
|       |-- x.class
|       |-- y.class
|       `-- z.class
|-- p.class
|-- q.class
|-- r.class
|-- res
|   |-- down.png
|   |-- keyboard.png
|   |-- media.png
|   |-- right.png
|   `-- up.png
|-- res1
|   |-- 0
|   |-- 1
|   |-- i
|   |-- i0
|   `-- INDEX
|-- s.class
|-- t.class
|-- theme
|   `-- 0
|       |-- bc.png
|       |-- bl.png
|       |-- b.png
|       |-- br.png
|       |-- checked.png
|       |-- font.bmf
|       |-- font_large.bmf
|       |-- font_xlarge.bmf
|       |-- icons.png
|       |-- list_bl.png
|       |-- list_b.png
|       |-- list_br.png
|       |-- list_l.png
|       |-- list_r.png
|       |-- list_tl.png
|       |-- list_t.png
|       |-- list_tr.png
|       |-- l.png
|       |-- p_bl.png
|       |-- p_b.png
|       |-- p_br.png
|       |-- p_l.png
|       |-- popup_bl.png
|       |-- popup_b.png
|       |-- popup_br.png
|       |-- popup_l.png
|       |-- popup_r.png
|       |-- popup_tl.png
|       |-- popup_t.png
|       |-- popup_tr.png
|       |-- p_r.png
|       |-- p_tl.png
|       |-- p_t.png
|       |-- p_tr.png
|       |-- r.png
|       |-- rss.png
|       |-- tc.png
|       |-- theme.xml
|       |-- theme.xml~
|       |-- Thumbs.db
|       |-- tl.png
|       |-- t.png
|       |-- tr.png
|       `-- unchecked.png
|-- tree
|-- tree.txt
|-- u.class
|-- v.class
|-- w.class
|-- x.class
|-- y.class
`-- z.class
```

12 directories, 290 files

I realized that the file I need to edit is a xml-like file located in **/res1/0**. Well I tried to edit and it worked. But there are some weired content on the top of this file which I have no clue about. here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html><body><a class="folder" href="w:html:2.xml">منو اول</a><a class="text" href="w:text:4.txt">منو دوم</a></body></html><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html><body><a class="text" href="w:text:3.txt">منو 1-1</a></body></html>منو 1-1سلام �
��  � � �ʡ$� �d�(��  ��4���ޏ� d-$�(�D( � �l�� ��՝  H�K�j�c��� ��(� �=a�_� �ۍI�
 ՜�� >�  �&  
�,�/� $
D-l�d�@ hl)D ؎H�� v B�� ��� `
P���[ �  �+� �H�,�(,L l�H-,,��$ �+ 5*�1�-�x�=9X �-n���H�Ĵm �� �4 �
 n�09���9�8-8�8 ��9� J>�.��,�����l�@�D-l�L�H�,,l
�!<,
G�� !�+�+ َB   Q�&  �h��<
 1� ��/b��| 4�,;� �ש :{  �����=*9��� y  �U�/�9��, �� �9 �� g��8X�Q���L�   �s�� ٘� f��<�  � �Y> � ��C8�=� �/�)E����d�@,L-d(`��,(,(�   ��O���A='>k?��n-j�E�+=��"� �� j;]�R �  � ��&�e c � ���� M�� `�����פ����I�W�MЎ�)9�(((�l�L�� �)F<�� �� �/�����(��\�� �9��� �+� < � �=����l�H,H�$ ��*�� x�ś�*�$L-��d) �$ ,�d���.�<��{ L)+�j: 9�/j ���<� E� �9��
I<b����,d:��;� �� � ު� @-H,L-l h�l
$�H��/l �    4�����   �  � � $;��� L)@�$  �,�,, (((��`;�+ �N� � �P�U�X9d�&=� (-�0a8�8]�p�`(A1b�  � �8� I������� B;� �,,�ڪƅ ) � � �l�(,,�D�ЮA�$� ���m� �k?�+  w; �& n�(Ľ*?Q8~�ѯ. ̜T    ��
�,��W�;�{>�,� �9&�� عQ�T U�k U��-g�� � "(�� ��88 5��*h w? �;�� �� "8�� 9�T�U�K�99�)k8� ���+�
E<�+� l�(� �(��, l�D � a�@
k ��
�  #���B(f8
</ ��B�`��f ==r9�*J G�ʋb I� <ùb(���W�H�vs�V N�r���rx����خ߉
�� `�L l�h��/��j8�=T��?�%��� �� �ٽ�<�
�!���< :� ��*��`-( d
 �خF�� P����/�d
d�@� �,�$�`�()ԯ�8�� �H   F O �b���͙� e�s�19��M�
����D�� s<b�h�������l  � -- l(@�l,��D;� � 9  �A<n9+<�    �\��
�
� Ӊ,��+�@ H��@��( H ,��h �*���Ɉ� ��-j���h�����RM��S�d��~E ,�v�������S8�w�e���m`���l��:e�W^e�s�m��3�` ��v��i΍w5D(,�� �WiŬ�n˄VS��r%n�S{`�R L���D@
�WY���a�����s�V��s|@
```

Can anyone help me to understand what is this and how can I edit such a thing!?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the data is either binary or of a different character set (Unicode?).  You should check how the file was originally created and you'll probably find your answer.

Comment: yes, this is unicode, this jar created with this app http://www.mobile4use.com/download-center/--/65----/download (need java run time to run 32bit win=> http://www.mobile4use.com/download-center/---/61-java-run-time-x86-u-20/download  64bit =>http://www.mobile4use.com/download-center/---/62-java-run-time-x64-u-20/download )

Comment: then the "weird content" is probably unicode characters.  Try opening it with MS Word, and you'll prolly see valid characters.  You may need to use the File > Open menu, selecting the file type as unicode.

Comment: i open this file with notepad++ & change encoding but No did not happen. this text in persian language [iran]

Comment: does notepad++ support unicode?  Are you sure the text is unicode, not another character set (like ISO 639-3)?

Comment: yes supported, my text in persian language (farsi) & text encoding is utf-8 (<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>)

Comment: sorry, then I'm pretty much outta ideas.  you might need to go back to mobile4use, and see if they're doing something funky with the data.